# Calculated Container Field Will Never Recalculate

Tags: filemaker

I have a `Container` field which is set as `Auto-enter Calculation replaces existing value`. I understand that fields do not recalculate after being set unless they are of type `Calculation`. Is there a way for me to have a dynamic image show in my container based on values in other fields and have the image change if the value in the field changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto-enter calculations set to replace existing value will recalculate on change of fields they depend on. Usually these fields are used right in the formula; if they are not, you can add a 'trigger' like this:

```
Case( True or MyField or MyOtherField /* trigger */;
    /* the rest of the formula */ )
```

this calculation will change when you change MyField or MyOtherField; the True is used to shortcut the expression and go straight to the formula. The fields must be in the same table; related fields won't work.